# Updating scala version

Tags: linux, scala, ubuntu

I want to update a Scala version. I know it be done for a project using scalaVersion function, but I also want to update a default scala version which is used when I type `scala` in the terminal.

Now I have 2.10.1 scala version.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://osgux.tumblr.com/post/44635945407/install-scala-2-10-0-in-ubuntu:

```
$ wget http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-2.10.3.tgz
$ tar zxf scala-2.10.3.tgz
$ sudo mv scala-2.10.3 /usr/local/scala
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/scala /usr/local/bin/scala
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/scalac /usr/local/bin/scalac
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/fsc /usr/local/bin/fsc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/sbaz /usr/local/bin/sbaz
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/sbaz-setup /usr/local/bin/sbaz-setup
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/scaladoc /usr/local/bin/scaladoc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/scala/bin/scalap /usr/local/bin/scalap
```

If you just want to install it for yourself, and not for everyone on the machine, replace `/usr/local/scala` with `~/tools/scala` (or some other subfolder of your home folder) and `/usr/local/bin` with `~/bin`.

Comment reply:

Since you already have Scala installed, you can look where Scala scripts are placed by using the command `which scala`. There are two possibilities:

1. if you see `/opt/scala/scala2.10-1/bin/scala`, this means `/opt/scala/scala2.10-1/bin` is in your `$PATH`. Find where it is added, and replace it with `/opt/scala/scala-2.10.3/bin`. Some likely places are `~/.profile`, `~/.bash-profile`, `~/.bashrc`, see others in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables (note that it lists the files I mentioned as "not recommended", but they are still widely used).
2. If you see `/usr/local/bin/scala` (or some other folder other then `/opt/scala/scala2.10-1/bin`), you should replace these files with links like this:

   ```
       $ sudo ln -sf /opt/scala/scala-2.10.3/bin/scala /usr/local/bin/scala
   ```

   (of course, using the correct folder if it isn't `/usr/local/bin`). Note that the first argument of `ln -s` is the file you are linking to, the second argument is the link you create, and `-f` removes the existing destination files.

Comment: What I like is that the major amount of answers about scala here I get from russian programmers.

Comment: @Alex, you should not do it like this. You should not manually move around files inside `/usr`. These files are under control of package manager, so in fact you should find actual `deb` package or PPA repository or you should create custom Scala installation in your `$HOME` and put its `bin` folder in your `$PATH`. But really, don't ever mess with your `/usr` system, it will eventually be a great pain for you.

Comment: I would also recommend creating `deb` package from Scala installation if you couldn't find one, but manual construction of `deb` packages is hard (in comparison with e.g. Archlinux packages), so it is better to create local installation and add it to `PATH`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Fair enough about `/usr/share`, but wouldn't `/usr/local` be all right? Or `/opt`. http://hivelogic.com/articles/using_usr_local/

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, you're creating links in `/usr/bin`. Imagine that you are trying to install a package which provides the same files in future. Don't know about `apt`, but package manager in Archlinux will complain about conflicting files. If, OTOH, you extract files to, say, `/usr/local/share/scala` or `/opt/scala`, and then add corresponding directories to `PATH`, it would be much better, you're right in this regard.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Yes, of course the links should go to `/usr/local/bin` in this case.

Comment: I don't understand. I installed scala in /opt/scala/scala2.10-3. There is also /opt/scala/scala2.10-1 there. Where do I add the sym links pointing to 2.10.3 of `scala`, `scalac`, `scalap`, etc? Is that `/usr/local/scala/bin/scala`, `/usr/local/scala/bin/scalac` and `/usr/local/scala/bin/scalap` instead of `/usr/bin/scala`, etc?